# Creating a Bobblehead Effect in Android

Tags: java, android, physics, gravity

I have no working code at all, but I will post my method of displaying images I need to bobble.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas can){
    can.drawBitmap(bobbleHead , xpos, ypos, p);
}
```

I have declared `xpos` and `ypos`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is for the head to move up and down, you need to use a `sin` function to modify ypos. For example, if you want the head to bob up and down once a second, you can calculate ypos using the time in seconds:

```
time = now - start;
ypos = ypos_at_rest + ypos_extension * sin(time * pi * 2.0);
```

Forgive me if the syntax is a little off, I'm extrapolating Java from C.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time getting this concept ported into android java...here's where I am at so far...

double d = (int) (time * Math.PI * 2.0);
ypos = (int) (50 + 15 * Math.sin(d));
can.drawBitmap(bobbleHead , xpos-(xpos/2), ypos, p);

time keeps getting and error...I'll keep trying different techniques.  Appreciate the direction!